# Navigation mvvm light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Someone could tell me why I can not change the page a second time?

For example, when I click login the application can change the page, ie, the main panel is displayed, however if the user clicks another button to open another panel nothing happens.

Main Windows

```
<Window x:Class="Smart.Interface.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Smart.Interface.View"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Smart.Interface.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024"
        DataContext="{Binding Login,
                              Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">


    <Grid Background="#FFE6E7E8">
        <Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="0" Name="RetanguloTop" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1024"/>
        <Rectangle Name="RetanguloFooter" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="0,703,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1024"/>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The first action works perfectly --> `CurrentViewModel = new PainelDeOpcoesViewModel();`

But in the view `PainelDeOpcoesView` I can no longer access any other view, utlizando the same idea.

`CurrentViewModel = new GerenciarUsuariosViewModel();` <-- it does not work

```
private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_currentViewModel == value)
                    return;
                _currentViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
            }
        }
```

My app.xaml

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"  d:IsDataSource="True" />

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
                <views:LoginView />
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PainelDeOpcoesViewModel}">
                <views:PainelDeOpcoesView />
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GerenciarUsuariosViewModel}">
                <views:GerenciarUsuariosView />
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Add this:
Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" ...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it did not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some bits are missing, but a guess is that CurrentViewModel needs to raise a PropertyChanged notification (implement INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
public object CurrentViewModel {
    get { return _currentViewModel; }
    set {
        _currentViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel"); //Ensure you have this or are binding to a DependencyProperty
    }
}
```

Please provide the code for your property if this does not fix it.

Comment: And this Locator.Login you are binding to, is that also where you are assigning CurrentViewModel?

Comment: That's it! As I said earlier the first action works, but when the main screen is loaded I no longer using and enjoying the same logic of action to load another page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result by creating a Data Template where **Viewmodel** acts as a **Key**  and **View** as its respective value.
Just Add the above DataTemplate to your xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTemplates:PainelDeOpcoesViewModel}">
    <DataTemplates:PainelDeOpcoesView></DataTemplates:PainelDeOpcoesView>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTemplates:GerenciarUsuariosViewModel}">
    <DataTemplates:GerenciarUsuariosView></DataTemplates:GerenciarUsuariosView>
</DataTemplate>
```

**On Button click**

```
CurrentViewModel = new PainelDeOpcoesViewModel();

                   OR

CurrentViewModel = new GerenciarUsuariosViewModel();
```